# Access to shadowed variable in Rust

Tags: variables, rust, shadowing

In Rust, is there a way to access the variable (that is declared in the main context) in the inner context while it is shadowed in the inner context?

Below is the code I tried. Looks like scope operator :: is not supported in Rust?

```rust
fn main() {
    let top_variable = 1;

    {
        println!("top variable in inner scope before shadowing = {}", top_variable);

        let top_variable = "abc";

        println!("top variable in the inner scope = {}", top_variable);
        println!("top variable accessed in the inner scope using scope parameter = {}", ::top_variable);
    }

    println!("top variable back in the main scope = {}", top_variable);
    let top_variable = 100;
    println!("top variable in the main scope and modified  = {}", top_variable);
}
```

Comment: No. The new variable literally shadows the previous, so you don't have a name to refer to it anymore

Comment: No, and that's a feature as far as I'm concerned. If you need to refer to both variables in the same context, just give them different names. Everything else will result in code that's horrible to read and understand.

Comment: Note that this kind of shadowing only happens for local variables within a single function, so the conflict can always be resolved locally and without affecting public interfaces.

Comment: > Looks like scope operator :: is not supported in Rust?
This `::top_variable` syntax doesn't work in any language I've used. In C++, for example, prefix `::` can only be used to access globals, not locals.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. confirmed my understanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Rust, is there a way to access the variable (that is declared in the main context) in the inner context while it is shadowed in the inner context?

no.

> Below is the code I tried. Looks like scope operator :: is not supported in Rust?

It's perfectly well supported, [it means "global path"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#path-qualifiers) so needs to be followed by a crate name (in edition 2018 and later).